# Why is my function not updating a global variable consisting of nested lists?(python)

Tags: python, function, global-variables, tic-tac-toe

I'm creating a function to display the variable *board*. The else portion of the function display_board is supposed to change the elements of *board* to '-'. The first if statement is for another variable of my program called locations, which works fine.
When I call display_board it outputs the correct format, but it doesn't actually alter *board*, as seen when it prints *board*.
Any ideas why it's not working?

Sidenote: this is for an intro programming class in python, therefore, nested lists is about as advanced as my knowledge/scope of class goes.

```
board = [

[' ', ' ', ' '],

[' ', ' ', ' '],

[' ', ' ', ' ']

]

def display_board(board):
    if board == locations:
        for row in locations:
            for column in row:
                print(column, end=' ')
        print()
# This chunk below is the important code that is not altering *board*
    else:
        for row in board:
            for column in row:
                if column == 'X':
                    print(column, end=' ')
                elif column == 'O':
                    print(column, end=' ')
                else:
                    column = '-'
                    print(column, end=' ')
            print()
display_board(board)
print(board)
```

output:

```
- - - 
- - - 
- - -
```

[[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to a variable doesn't modify the list element that the variable value was originally copied from. You need to assign to the list element itself. Change the second loop so you get the list indexes, then you can assign to that element.

```
    for row in board:
        for index, column in enumerate(row):
            if column == 'X':
                print(column, end=' ')
            elif column == 'O':
                print(column, end=' ')
            else:
                row[index] = '-'
                print(row[index], end=' ')
        print()
```